# Scalp's hair is NOT affected by "wind" forcefield effector but cube primitive IS

Tags: particles, hair, force-fields

I am trying to move my hair using a wind forcefield object.
It does not have any effect.

However, when I create a new cube mesh and attach **identical hair** to that and place it within the **same wind effector**, the cube's hair **is** effected.

What am I doing wrong?

Please see [my blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/47741) for a simple recreation of the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, very simple solution.

The forcefield must exist on the **same layer** as the particle system under the object data tab to be affected.

Use shift+left click to add multiple layers to the wind forcefield.
See picture attached.

[image]